# How to set up Apache reverse proxy with SSL encryption?

Tags: web-services, apache, https

I have a web app that serves an application over HTTP. I want to set up an HTTPS proxy server that simply mirrors that web app. The connection between the proxy and the actual web app server doesn't need to be encrypted because it will all be behind our firewall.

To explain in more detail, right now I have an app:

```
http://IPAddress:8081/app
```

I want to enable this:

```
https://app.mycompany.com:8443/app
```

without actually setting up HTTPS on the original web server ("IPAddress"). The reasons I need to do this are somewhat complicated but I'm not a big Apache guy and feel immediately lost when I go to do this task! If it helps I'm running Ubuntu!

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Figured this out. By far the best way to do it is nginx. Took me 5 minutes to setup a reverse proxy that works perfectly. You just make a virtual host pointing at the internal webserver and nginx does the rest. It even gives you cool features like redundancy and load balancing that can be used in case the core web app server fails for any reason. Just in case anyone sees this and needs the same thing!